# knockout binding - working with javascript objects but not json object

Tags: knockout.js

I'm trying to learn knockoutjs by studying existing sourcecodes and making small changes to them.. The source code that I'm trying to understand here is an example of knockout-sortable.js by RP Niemeyer.

The original example code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/UdXr4/).

The intent is to be able to get data from server in either json string or jtoken object and use it in code..

I make a small change to it and do a console.log to get json [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UdXr4/748/)

```
var initialTables = [
        new Table("Table One",  [
            new Student(1, "Bobby", "male"),
            new Student(2, "Ted", "male"),
            new Student(3, "Jim", "male")
        ]),
        new Table("Table Two", [
            new Student(4, "Michelle", "female"),
            new Student(5, "Erin", "female"),
            new Student(6, "Chase", "male")
        ]),
        new Table("Table Three", [
            new Student(7, "Denise", "female"),
            new Student(8, "Chip", "male"),
            new Student(9, "Kylie", "female")
        ]),
        new Table("Table Four", [
            new Student(10, "Cheryl", "female"),
            new Student(11, "Doug", "male"),
            new Student(12, "Connor", "male")
        ]),
        new Table("Table Five", [
            new Student(13, "Cody", "male"),
            new Student(14, "Farrah", "female"),
            new Student(15, "Lyla", "female")
        ])
    ];

this.tables = ko.observableArray(initialTables);
```

The initialTables object gets converted to json using `console.log(ko.toJSON(this.tables))` which can be seen in console.log and is shown below.

```
[{"students":[{"id":1,"name":"Bobby","gender":"male"},{"id":2,"name":"Ted","gender":"male"},{"id":3,"name":"Jim","gender":"male"}]},{"students":[{"id":4,"name":"Michelle","gender":"female"},{"id":5,"name":"Erin","gender":"female"},{"id":6,"name":"Chase","gender":"male"}]},{"students":[{"id":7,"name":"Denise","gender":"female"},{"id":8,"name":"Chip","gender":"male"},{"id":9,"name":"Kylie","gender":"female"}]},{"students":[{"id":10,"name":"Cheryl","gender":"female"},{"id":11,"name":"Doug","gender":"male"},{"id":12,"name":"Connor","gender":"male"}]},{"students":[{"id":13,"name":"Cody","gender":"male"},{"id":14,"name":"Farrah","gender":"female"},{"id":15,"name":"Lyla","gender":"female"}]}]
```

Now I change initialTables to the json object I recd earlier and call tables as shown below and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UdXr4/749/)

this.tables = ko.observableArray(ko.mapping.fromJS(initialTables));

Now, even though I do not see any errors, I do not see the initialTables object reflected in the results pane..

What am I doing wrong??

All help is sincerely appreciated..

Thanks

Comment: just make a change like this `ko.mapping.fromJS(initialTables)()` fiddle  here http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/udxr4/750/

Comment: @supercool, please don't be shy to make an answer instead of comments if it is really an answer. Firstly, it would give a chance to accept an answer for the TS, and secondly it would help the others to skip questions that have accepted answer already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well `arnab` you are missing braces`()` which should do your work .

Please do the modification in this line

```
ko.observableArray(ko.mapping.fromJS(initialTables))
```

to something like

```
ko.observableArray(ko.mapping.fromJS(initialTables)())
```

To a observable array you need to pass `Array` . If you give `()` at the end you get a Array (unwrapping content) .

Working fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/udxr4/750/)**